# Why is calling a method on an object literal slower on V8?

Tags: javascript, performance, v8

I was surprised by the results of this [simple jsperf test](http://jsperf.com/function-call-on-js-objects):

```
Benchmark.prototype.setup = function() {
  var O = function() {
      this.f = function(){};
  }
  var o = new O();
  var o2 = {
      f : function(){}
  };
};

// Test case #1
o.f();  // ~721M ops/s

// Test case #2
o2.f(); // ~135M ops/s
```

I expected both to perform the same (and in fact the performance is similar in Firefox). V8 must be optimizing something on case #1, but what?

Comment: If you give the function something to do to make the compliler uncertain of the outcome, you might find performance is roughly the same for both methods (per other browsers including IE and Safari).

Comment: I updated the tests to do that, but the difference is still noticeable (2x).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First fundamentals about V8 and jsPerf:

- V8 uses an technique called *hidden classes*. Each hidden class describes a certain object shape e.g. *object has property `x` at offset `16`* or *object has method `f`* and these hidden classes are connected together with *transitions* as the object is mutated forming *transition trees* (which are  strictly speaking dags). Not all hidden classes reside in the same transition tree; instead a new transition tree is born from each constructor. Take a look at [these slides](http://mrale.ph/talks/cwp2013/#/25) to grasp the basic idea behind hidden classes.
- When jsPerf does the following to run your test: given `setup` and `body` it **multiple times** generates and runs a function looking approximately like this:

  ```js
  function measure() {
    /* setup */
    var start = Date.now();
    for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      /* body */
    }
    var end = Date.now();

    /* N / (start - end) determines ops / ms reported */
  }
  ```

  Each run is called a *sample*.

Now lets take a look at transition trees in your benchmark.

1. Hidden class of `o` belongs to the transition tree with a root at constructor `O`. Notice that each constructor is invoked a single time. This allows V8 to build the following transition tree in memory:

   ```js
   O{} -f-> O{ f: <closure> }
   ```

   The hidden class of `o` essentially tells V8 that `o` has a *method called `f` implemented by given closure*. This allows a V8's optimizing compiler to inline `f` in your benchmark above which essentially makes benchmarking loop empty.
2. Hidden class of `o2` belongs to the transition tree of `Object`. First notice that `setup` is invoked multiple times so if V8 tried to apply the same optimization with promoting `f` to a method it would arrive to an impossible transition tree:

   ```js
   Object{} -f-> Object{ f: <closure> }
            -f-> Object{ f: <other closure> }
   ```

   In fact, V8 does not even try. V8 implementors foresaw this situation and V8 just makes `f` a normal property:

   ```js
   Object{} -f-> Object{ f: <property at offset 8> }
   ```

   Thus to invoke `o2.f()` it needs to load it first and this also impairs inlining.

Here you should realize one important thing: if you invoke `O` constructor twice then V8 will arrive to the same impossible transition tree that V8 avoids hitting for `Object`:

```js
    O{} -f-> O{ f: <closure> }
        -f-> O{ f: <other closure> }
```

You can't have structure like that. In this case V8 on the fly converts `f` to a field instead of making it a method and rewrites transition tree:

```js
    O{} -f-> O{ f: <property at offset 8> }
```

See this effect in http://jsperf.com/function-call-on-js-objects/3 where I added one `new O()` before you create `o`. You will notice that the performance of object literal and object constructed with `new` are the same.

Another detail here is that V8 would try to turn `f` into a method for the literal as well, if the literal is declared in the *global scope*. See http://jsperf.com/function-call-on-js-objects/5 and [Issue 2246](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2246) against V8. The reasoning here is simple: literal in the global scope is evaluated only once so it's likely that such promotion will succeed and there will be no clashes between methods that would arise if literal is evaluated multiple times.

You can read more about similar issues in [my blog post](http://mrale.ph/blog/2013/08/14/hidden-classes-vs-jsperf.html).

Comment: About /3: Objects constructed with `new` should define methods in `.prototype` in which case making many objects would not cause the same effect and `new` will win again. Sadly the difference is often too subtle at language level and many new js developers (and even some old) don't see a difference between defining methods on .prototype vs dynamically in constructor body.

Answer (score 2):

V8 makes optimizations for known prototypes. In other words, usage and creation of objects via `new` is optimized.

You can write more similar tests and this will always be the conclusion.

In the second case, you're blinding the engine. It doesn't know why, if or when `o2` will have an attribute.

Comment: But I'm calling an own method, not one from the prototype.

Comment: By calling `O` via `new`, you trigger the optimizations. V8 knows `O` will have an `f` attribute, and lookup time is reduced significantly. I'm sure there's other reasons I don't know, too

Comment: *usage and creation of objects via new is optimized* – Crockford is probably swearing at that :)

Comment: @bfavaretto— *"Ah, that makes sense"*. Not to me.The only optimisation I can see is that the compiler knows that the function doesn't do anything or return any value so it doesn't actually run it. Why it doesn't come to the same conclusion in the second case is beyond me.

Comment: @RobG Okay, I'm unaccepting this to see if something else comes up, but I think uʍop ǝpısdn is right. If the compiler knows beforehand which methods `o` has, a lookup is avoided. That makes sense, doesn't it?

Comment: @FelixKling—thanks for that, but I still don't see why the two are treated differently since an Object literal is very similar.

Comment: @RobG: I guess objects from object literals are always treated as hash maps and not optimized. Or something like that.

Comment: I cannot say off-hand what causes the difference, but this answer is not correct. Object literals use very similar optimisations.

Comment: @AndreasRossberg When compared to constructors that define methods dynamically as in the OP, yes. But using `new` enables you to use `.prototype` (use the same method for different objects). That's what I think the answer is referring to.  (why the OP isn't doing that is beyond me)